# Wrapping a ko.mapping.fromJS() as a ko.observable()

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to wrap js object into an observable()?

i.e.

```
//initialization
var CompositeModel = {
 propertyOne: null,
 propertyTwo: null
};
myClass.myContent = **ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(CompositeModel))**;


//everytime I get an update I call
ko.mapping.fromJS(newCompositeModel, myClass.myContent);
```

but it seems that if I do this my view doesn't get anything if my view binding is something like this:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: myContent.propertyOne"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ko.mapping.fromJS makes all your properties observable anyway, so I'm not sure why you would want to wrap the mapping up in another observable. I have knocked up a jsFiddle to demonstrate mapping a javascript object into your view model and then updating that mapping at a later point.

http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/ztNtc/4/

```
<p data-bind="text: propertyOne"></p>
<p data-bind="text: propertyTwo"></p>
<input type="button" value="Update model" data-bind="click: updateMe"/>

var CompositeModel = {
 propertyOne: 'hi',
 propertyTwo: 'there'
};

var newCompositeModel = {
 propertyOne: 'how are',
 propertyTwo: 'you?'
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(CompositeModel);

viewModel.updateMe = function() {ko.mapping.fromJS(newCompositeModel, viewModel)}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I suspect that @user964228's problem is the same as the one I'm running into--he's updating a model that is in a field of his viewModel object, and elements data-bound on those fields either bellyache that the field doesn't exist before it does, or if you load up the object with fields, don't see the change when it updates with data.